# Ionic ion-textarea setFocus when view loaded not working

Tags: ionic3

I have a ionic3 ion-textarea:

```
<ion-content padding class="note-detail">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-textarea #myInput [(ngModel)]="note.content"
                   (ngModelChange)="textValueChanged()" placeholder="" rows="6"></ion-textarea>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

I want to auto focus this text area when this view is loaded.

If I setFocus directly, it will lost focus instantly (keyboard show and hide):

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
      this.myInput.setFocus();
  }
```

If I set a timeout, nothing will happen, textarea not focused at all:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("set timeout fired!");
      this.myInput.setFocus();
    },1000);
  }
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

What if you force to open the keyboard?

```
import { Keyboard } from 'ionic-native';

ionViewDidLoad() {

 setTimeout(() => {
   Keyboard.show(); 
   this.myInput.setFocus();
 }, 1000);

}
```

Ref: [Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use autofocus attribute:

```
<ion-textarea autofocus ... ></ion-textarea>
```

Regards

Comment: It works only once. The second loading is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I just fixed it. Since the `ionic-plugin-keyboard` deprecated, the `native-keyboard` doesn't work (at least it doesn't work for me).

`native-keyboard` API doucument: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/

Deprecated: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard

I also tried `Keyboard` in `ionic-angular` but it doesn't work for me either.

===============================================================

Anyways here is how I fixed it:

Install the new one `cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard`: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard

**In component:**

```
...
declare var Keyboard: any;
...
export class MapSearchbarModal {
    @ViewChild("searchbar") searchbar: Searchbar;
...
    ionViewDidLoad() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.searchbar.setFocus();
        Keyboard.show();
      }, 100);
    }
...
}
```

**In HTML:**

```
<ion-searchbar #searchbar
...
</ion-searchbar>
```